# git diff ignoring whitespace unless a space is deleted

Tags: git, whitespace

If I use  `git diff --ignore-space-change --ignore-all-space` to get only relevant changes, I miss changes, where a **space between two words was completely deleted**.

Example

```
echo       "the space before this string is irrelevant"
echo "foo bar are two words"
```

changes to

```
echo "the space before this string is irrelevant"
echo "foobar are two words"
```

I wouldn't see the change gluing foo and bar together, creating a new single word.

I want to see those (sometimes really relevant) changes in the git diff output, something like

```
git diff --ignore-space-change-unless-no-space-left
```

Comment: Is that diff reported with `--word-diff` ? (the output wouldn't be a regular patch, though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out `--ignore-all-space`.

```
$ cat f1 f2
echo       "the space before this string is irrelevant"
echo "foo bar are two words"
echo "the space before this string is irrelevant"
echo "foobar are two words"
$ git diff --ignore-space-change f1 f2
diff --git a/f1 b/f2
index c9f73d1..fba75e4 100644
--- a/f1
+++ b/f2
@@ -1,2 +1,2 @@
 echo "the space before this string is irrelevant"
-echo "foo bar are two words"
+echo "foobar are two words"
```